# Update database column in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have a problem, 
I want to update my database's "active" column.
my schema =

```
 tablename(name:string , id:int , active:0 ,created_at)
```

I want to update active attribute in my rails app after a certain period of time let say 2 days from the created_at time

I have tried few stuff like this from controller but none of this worked for me..
can anyone help ?

```
def check_aim
  @aim = Aim.find(1)

  aimdays = @aim.day
  futuredate = @aim.created_at+aimdays.days
  if(Time.now == futuredate)
    @aim.active = false # i have tried @aim.update_attribute(:active,1) also didn't word either
    @aim.save
  end
  if @aim.save
    saved
  else
    not saved  
  end
end
helper_method :check_aim
```

view class

```
=debug check_aim
```

this returns

```
saved
```

but when i see my database nothing has changed ... plz help

Comment: Set `@aim.active = 1` and save

Comment: default value is 1

Comment: and you want it to set to `0` ?

Comment: Why are you using an integer and not a boolean column in the first place? Even better would be to use an [enum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html).

Comment: it seems default is 0

Comment: I have access to my mysql database I can see the value stored currently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out..  stupid rails

Guys this is the most stupid thing by rails...
it was nothing but the problem of keyword 'active'
i changed column name from active to status and now it works fyn..
damm it !!! I wasted hours on this :/

Answer (score 2):

To genuinely update a column after a certain amount of time, one way would be to run a cron script. The script could run every day to check the table and update the `active` fields that are not set to active 2 days after the `created_at` date.

Comment: The problem is he is not able to save

Comment: Shannon .. well how may i implement a cron scriipt and what else can i do if not Time.now == future date ?

Answer (score 1):

There is possibility that the condition `Time.now == futuredate` is failing but still `@aim.save` will return you `true` as it can be saved with no change.

You need to change it to `Time.now >= futuredate` so if the `futuredate` is passed the `active` will be set to `0`

You may move the `puts` statements inside the block and check whether it's printing something

```
def check_aim
  @aim = Aim.find(1)

  aimdays = @aim.day
  futuredate = @aim.created_at + aimdays.days
  if(Time.now >= futuredate)
    @aim.active = 0 # i have tried @aim.update_attribute(:active,1) also didn't word either
    if @aim.save
      "saved"
    else
      "not saved"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: yes I tried and results came out that TIme.now == futuredate is failing

Comment: how may I fix this

Comment: check for `Time.now >= futuredate`

Comment: thanks .. it passes now but data still not updated in db the major problem.